# SQL query distinct with case function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following data:

```
ID  Owner
--------
01  Sarah
01  Andrew
02  Sarah
03  Andrew
04  Andrew
04  Sarah
05  Andrew
```

And I want to get to the following output:

```
ID  Grouped_Owners
---------
01  Andrew and Sarah
02  Sarah
03  Andrew
04  Andrew and Sarah
05  Andrew
```

And I've tried this query (and other iterations of similar approaches):

```
select 
  distinct(id)
  , case 
      when count(id) > 1 then 'Andrew and Sarah'
      else owner
    end as Grouped_Owners
from Ads
group by id, Owner
order by id
```

... but I can't get to the results. I'm *suspecting* that I might need to use windowing/partition function, but that's seems overkill.  I've searched around the interwebs, but I can't seem to find anything that fits this use case :/

I'm sure this will be a very quick answer for the gurus here! :)  Thanks!

Comment: `MySQL` or `Postgresql`?

Comment: Redshift, my apologies.  I've found what I need now:  listagg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) along with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(Owner SEPARATOR ' and ') AS Grouped_Owners
FROM Ads
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

---

[**Check Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/308af6/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance 1000111 :)  You've put me on the correct path:  There’s group_concat in MySQL, string_agg in Postgres, and listagg in redshift.    I needed the listagg, but group_concat definitely works for my purpose on mysql too.  Thanks! :)